# Activity not updating properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android, so maybe I'm doing something horribly wrong. I want to have a particular Activity that shows details about an instance of a "Creature" class for a game. Name, damage taken, that sort of thing.

I'm having a problem getting the creature data to be properly shown in the GUI objects. Both at initial creation (where it should copy the creature's name into the name field) and when a damage mark is added (where it doesn't update to show the proper image).

Here's my mini-example of what I have:

```
public class CreatureDetailActivity2 extends Activity
{
  Creature creature;

  public void addMark(View v)
  {
    // connected to the button via android:onClick="addMark" in the XML
    creature.getTrack().addDamage(DamageType.Normal, 1);
    refreshDisplay();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(creature.getName())
        .setMessage(creature.getTrack().toString()).show();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_creature_detail);
    creature = new Creature("Example");
    refreshDisplay();
  }


  public void refreshDisplay()
  {
    final View creatureDetailView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.activity_creature_detail, null);

    final EditText nameField = (EditText) (creatureDetailView
        .findViewById(R.id.textbox_creature_name));
    nameField.setText(creature.getName());

    final ImageView damageBox0 = (ImageView) (creatureDetailView.findViewById(R.id.damageBox0));
    damageBox0.setImageResource(R.drawable.__n);
    // in the full program this does the same for 0 through 9, but this is a sample
    // also, in the full program, this is a dynamic lookup for the correct pic
    // but again, this is just a sample version.
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that the app will load up and start, but then none of the widgets will update properly. You can click the button, and it'll show the AlertDialog, and the text of the AlertDialog will change, but the textfield in the activity won't be changed, and the ImageView doesn't change at any point from what it starts as to the one it's supposed to change to.

So I'm very stumped. I can post more about the project's setup if I'm leaving out something important, but I'm not even sure what the problem going on is so I'm not sure what else to include in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final View creatureDetailView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.activity_creature_detail, null);
```

Inflates your Activity's layout into basically nothing, just returning the View it inflated. `setContentView` is what actually inflates your layout into the Activity's View hierarchy.

Once you inflate your layout you don't need to do it again. Just use `findViewById` without the reference to a dangling unattached View.

Change your refreshDisplay method to this:

```
public void refreshDisplay()
{
    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox_creature_name);
    nameField.setText(creature.getName());

    final ImageView damageBox0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.damageBox0);
    damageBox0.setImageResource(R.drawable.__n);
    // in the full program this does the same for 0 through 9, but this is a sample
    // also, in the full program, this is a dynamic lookup for the correct pic
    // but again, this is just a sample version.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changes because You do it completely wrong.

If You wish to update any view element of current activity You do it like this

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.element);
v.setText("text");
```

this is just simple example.
You would need to cast a returned element to correct type like to be able to access all available methods.

What You do wrong is trying to inflate a layout again.